# How to show that $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n/4}{n \choose m}2^{-n}\leq \exp(-n/8)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

For simplicity sake assume that $n/4$ is a natural number, how can I show that $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n/4}{n \choose m}2^{-n}\leq \exp(-n/8)$. I attempted using the approximation $(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}\xrightarrow{n \to \infty}\exp(x)$ or the binomial formula but neither helped.

Comment: It may be useful: https://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18310S15/chernoff-notes.pdf  theorem 4, (ii) for $\delta = \frac12$ and $p_i = \frac12$.

Comment: @BotnakovN. Yes, but I get $\leq \exp(-n/16)$ and not $\leq \exp(-n/8)$

Comment: maybe with [Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Comment: This appears to come from Hoeffding's inequality with $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{4}$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality. The proof is given in the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, lets replace $n \to 4n$, so that it is equivalent to show $\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^n \binom{4n}{m} \leqslant 2^{4n}e^{-n/2}$. We need a good bound for the partial sum in LHS, so consider
$$\binom{4n}{m-1} = \frac{(4n)!}{m!(4n-m)!}\cdot \frac{m}{4n-m+1} < \binom{4n}{m}\cdot\frac13 \tag{for $m<n$}$$
As $1+\frac13+\frac1{3^2}+\dots  = \frac32$, we get the bound $\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^n \binom{4n}m < \frac32\binom{4n}n$ for the partial sum. Now, using an easily found and rather well known upper bound for binomial coefficients, viz. $\binom{n}k < \frac{n^k}{k!}$, it is enough to show
$$\frac32 \frac{(4n)^n}{n!}< 2^{4n}\cdot e^{-n/2}$$
which is straightforward by induction.

Comment: Very straightforward and uses far less machinery than Hoeffding’s Inequality. +1